# Is there a word for the joy a smart aleck feels when they point out to other people how stupid they are?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word for the joy a smart aleck feels when they point out to other people how stupid they are?  Prideful seems too general.  I want a word that points to intellectual hubris but also compels people to actively seek out people "stupider" than they are, just so they can try to humiliate them?  Some sort of sick, warped, sensual pleasure out of being an intellectual?

an example sentence might be:

The professor would spend his evenings on Facebook, debating religion and enjoying the feeling of ___________ that came from punishing stupid people for their idiocies.

Comment: these are both good words, but I am looking for something a bit more sensuous.  Something that captures the smile of joy on their face, the kind of ecstatic feeling they get, when they are punishing others for their stupidity.

Comment: @Sarah Please ensure the actual text of your question conveys everything you need. Don't put relevant information in comments. There's a checklist in [tag info](/tags/single-word-requests/info) which will help. Note that a requirement of this sort of question is a sample sentence **with a blank** where your word will go.

Comment: The one close vote that this question has attracted (as I write this) asserts that the question belongs on another site in the network. Any thoughts as to the identity of that other site?

Comment: I think this question breaks the rules of SE regarding respect for the beliefs of other members. I happen to be an atheist, but I am able to frame a question on SE EL&U about "smart alecs" that doesn't use an example that implies Christians are stupid people whose beliefs are idiocies. And if this professor is a real person, then the question also breaks the rules because you are asking for help in attacking someone. If neither of these are true or intended then you need to radically revise your question so that it cannot be interpretted in this manner.

Comment: @David Or the asker is writing a novel and wants help getting this particular sentence right. That would not be objectionable. Hard to know without context.

Comment: I agree with David, the example seems a little too life like, it fits in too smoothly with how a Christian feels, so they tell me, around the **One God Less**-people at university. The example could have been more neutral. As it is written, it's offensive to atheists.

Comment: Not an answer, but this question title immediately made me think of the sentence: *"The fact that you know more about the system and they know less about the system doesn’t make you a superior being who should look down upon all users with disdain from your high castle on the shimmering peak of Smarter-Than-You Mountain."*  :)  (From [the fundamental philosophy of debugging](http://www.codesimplicity.com/post/the-fundamental-philosophy-of-debugging/).)

Comment: Isn't this trolling. If not, then *this* definitely is! ;-)

Comment: I don't know that a word for this exists. It would probably be the same word used for sadistic joy if such a word exists, as taking joy in humiliating others is a form of sadism. However, if I saw a professor becoming happy after seeking out people on Facebook to debate, I would assume it was joy derived from helping others learn, or from having their points heard, rather than the sadistic pleasure of seeing others proved wrong.

Comment: @David isn't this question actually implying that atheists are smug odious people? Maybe that's why you're annoyed at this question? (I'm an atheist too, BTW)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm — No. The poster describes a particular atheist, but originally referred to Christians as a group. Nor has she responded to my criticism. My comment was part of review work on SE which is, as you will know, run by its users. The question holds no interest for me. I would point out that your comments also violate the SE guidelines by being personal in nature. You impute the emotion of anger to me because I criticised a post. That is a non sequitur. You then proceed to try to explain my imagined anger in terms of my imagined personal emotions. That is off limits.

Answer (score 76):

I'd say "[smug](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/smug)" which means self-satisfaction, but is also often associated with a particularly condescending facial expression. And with your specific comment about the smile, something like this:

"His smug smile revealed his pleasure in showing us up as fools..."

Comment: smug is certainly close.  maybe that is the best word

Comment: This was my first thought.  "Smugness" as a noun can be used directly in the example sentence sentence, "smug superiority" also works in combination.

Comment: *Smug satisfaction* is the term which fits.

Answer (score 19):

I'd use [superiority](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/superiority?s=t) or [self-satisfaction](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-satisfaction?s=t)

**Superiority**'s definition looks benign, but it's usual usage indicates something along the lines you're after. See the example of contemporary usage:

> He is a narcissistic rogue who is utterly convinced of his own brilliance and *superiority* to those around him.

**Self-Satisfaction**'s definition looks closer to what you've asked; however, Dictionary.com's contemporary usage examples ironically are more benign. A good example of its use is:

> They are so self-opiniated [sic], and so full of *self-satisfaction*, that it is hard to be patient with them.

In the context, you could also use **self-congratulation**

Answer (score 14):

The scenario you describe reminds me of a German word. While it may not be an *exact* fit, it fits nevertheless.

[Schadenfreude](https://www.bing.com/search?q=what%20is%20a%20german%20word%20for%20getting%20pleasure%20from%20the%20misery%20of%20others%3F&form=EDNTHT&mkt=en-us&httpsmsn=1&refig=4e827379ba964233adc9794224ef24ad&sp=-1&pq=undefined&sc=0-35&qs=n&sk=&cvid=4e827379ba964233adc9794224ef24ad)

Schadenfreude is pleasure derived from the misfortunes of others. This word is taken from German and literally means "harm-joy". It is the feeling of joy or pleasure when one sees another fail or suffer misfortune. It is also borrowed by some other languages.

Comment: almost this, except I think one usually feels schadenfreude when watching a pain you did not cause, not one you did cause.  One you hoped would happen, but would never actively try to do yourself.

Comment: @Sarah:  As I said, it's not an exact fit! I, too, like "smug." Don

Comment: The entire OP cried out for the answer schadenfreude, and it is not limited to the source of the harm.

Comment: No, that is precisely the problem @YosefBaskin.   If *you* are the source of harm, then other words are so much more appropriate that schadenfreude  is not.  Also, since there are so many better words for "gaining while you're losing", schadenfreude  implies you are not gaining.  And more likely, losing too.  Like when you can't afford a dike, and your neighbor can but goes "haha, I'll never need one, the government dike will hold", and you dogpaddle over and ask "how's that big savings working out for you?"

Comment: Schadenfreude, in fact, is more like the feeling you get when our smug professor dies, and finds himself waiting at the pearly gates... :)

Comment: But... but... this is English.StackExchange.com.  So wouldn't epicaricacy be more appropriate?

Comment: @TOOGAM: Touché! Don

Comment: It is the same term (but translated) in Danish, and indicates pleasure of seeing others suffer.  It is implicit not to be causing the suffering.  Most likely picked up from German.

Comment: This is very different.

Comment: As a German native speaker, I have to say that Schadenfreude is a **completely different** concept. Schadenfreude is when you are happy that something bad occurred to somebody else - typically either because you find it funny (think somebody slipping on a banana peel) or because you just don't like the person and are happy that bad things are happening to them.

Answer (score 9):

Consider [self-righteousness](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-righteous?s=t), which fits particularly well in your example of baiting religious folks.

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-righteousness) also suggests sanctimoniousness, sententiousness and  and holier-than-thou attitudes.

Answer (score 7):

Supercilious may be a fit depending whether or not the person feeling it is actually somewhat more knowledgeable, failing that glib.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with arrogant, but I also like **vainglory**

> **vain·glo·ry** 
> inordinate pride in oneself or one's achievements; excessive vanity.

This is similar to arrogance except I associate arrogance with a negative feeling toward the person you are correcting, whereas with vainglory its more about how great you feel about yourself, not necessarily relative to the other person.

Answer (score 5):

Superiority is an exact fit for the sentence.

Comment: yep "feeling of superiority" fits the example sentence well and I see you posted it first. You should add some dictionary definition in  your answer supporting this choice though.

Answer (score 2):

"Mastery" is the feeling he is enjoying. He probably feels smug and superior, but those, like the enjoyment he experiences, are secondary to his sense of mastery.

Collins Dictionary offers these two definitions, among other information, for "masterful":

1. fond of acting the part of a master; domineering; imperious
2. having or showing the ability of a master; expert; skillful; masterly

The professor would spend his evenings on facebook, debating religion with Christians, enjoying the feeling of mastery that came from punishing stupid people for their idiocies.

Answer (score 1):

how about condescending? from Collins: If you say that someone is condescending, you are showing your disapproval of the fact that they talk or behave in a way which shows that they think they are superior to other people.

Answer (score 0):

> The professor would spend his evenings on Facebook, debating religion with Christians, enjoying punishing stupid people for their idiocies.

The feeling is 'enjoying', he's enjoying it.

You asked for a perjorative word, but the sentence describes what the Professor is feeling - internally - and he isn't feeling something perjorative against himself, he feels good.

To fit a perjorative in the sentence has to come from the third person narrator and their judgement, i.e. an observation visible to an outsider - something about how he looks or behaves, e.g.

> [..] debating religion with Christians, enjoying punishing stupid people for their idiocies, his lips curling into a cruel and self-congratulatory smile and his fingers a blur, yet every sentence he typed was the same. SMUG SMUG S M U G.

Answer (score -2):

How about, "Humbug" or "Gloating"?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).